# How to use Parent model's column in Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have these 3 models: **Timesheet, EmployeeLeaveRequest, EmployeeLeaveRequestDates**. The Timesheet and EmployeeLeaveRequest are somehow related. Every employee has many timesheets and many leave_requests. I want to get the leave_requests that are related to the timesheet based on employee_id and date (schedule_time_in).

Timesheet Table

| timesheet_id | employee_id | schedule_time_in | schedule_time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-03-03 08:00:00 | 2022-03-03 17:00:00 |

EmployeeLeaveRequest Table

| request_id | employee_id | employee_leave_daterange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-03-03 - 2022-03-04 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-03-05 - 2022-03-05 |

EmployeeLeaveRequest Table

| request_date_id | request_id | request_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-03-03 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-03-04 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-03-05 |

I have tried this code in Timesheet model but this doesn't work. I'm putting this here just for the idea on what I wanted to do.

```
public function leave_requests() {
    $timesheet_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->schedule_time_in)->format('Y-m-d');

    return $this->hasMany(EmployeeLeaveRequest::class, 'employee_id', 'employee_id')
        ->with(['leave_request_dates' => function ($query) use ($timesheet_date) {
            $query->whereDate('request_date', '=', $timesheet_date);
        }]);
}
```

**EDIT:**
in the code above, it would work if the $timesheet_date is a static value e.g '2022-03-03'. So i'm thinking maybe i'm close to what I wanted to do. So i want to know how to get the value of **schedule_time_in** of the timesheet so i can pass it as parameter in the ->whereDate condition

Comment: why don't you establish relation between `EmployeeLeaveRequest` and `Timesheet` by `employee_id` field?

Comment: yes i already did that. the code is at the bottom of my question --leave_requests(). but it returns all leave requests of the employee instead of just the ones that have the same date as the timesheet

Comment: btw, i am referring to the leave_requests() function but without the $timesheet_date variable and the ->with()